# Three different numbers from the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. In how many ways can he do this so that the three numbers are not consecutive?

Tags: combinatorics

Three different numbers from the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. In how many ways can he do this so that the three numbers are not consecutive?

So it's C (6,3)=20
There are 4 types that are consecutive (1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5), (4,5,6)
So there are 16 ways.

I keep getting 16 but it's not right. Can I get help?

Comment: Are $2,5,7$ and $7,2,5$ different ways?

Comment: Why do you think that answer is not correct?

Comment: @lulu because the application I'm answering to doesn't accept it.

Comment: Well...perhaps there is an issue with what "consecutive" means.  Maybe they want "no two numbers are consecutive" or something like that.

Comment: @ajotatxe I don't think so

Comment: @lulu I don't think so because the answer would be 2 right? I already checked that.

Comment: Well, $(1,3,5), (1,3,6), (1,4,6), (2,4,6)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes the answer was indeed 4. (1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,4,6),(2,4,6) were the answers. The wording was just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Why is $16$ not right? There are exactly four consecutive sequences of length three from members of that set, as you found, and indeed $$\binom{6}{3}=\frac{6×5×4}{3!}=20,$$ so your deduction is correct.

Or did you mean *arithmetic progressions* of length three, for that's quite a different thing?

Comment: It seems the intended question was "In how many ways can three different numbers from the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ be selected so that no two of the selected numbers are consecutive?''  That said, your interpretation of the question makes perfect sense.